How do I get PyCharm 2024 to use the right Python version?
My company computer came pre-installed with Python version 3.13. Unfortunately, the standard we've been using for the past few years is version 3.7.0, which means a lot of our packages/venvs are incompatible with version 3.13. So, I uninstalled 3.13 and installed 3.7.0.
Unfortunately, every time I attempt to create a new interpreter, it keeps defaulting back to 3.13, even though I uninstalled it and specifically set the path to 3.7. I also made sure to update my environment variables and restart my computer.
Below are images showing me setting up a new Python interpreter (I made sure to clear out all pre-existing interpreters and venvs for the project beforehand):
The interpreter location I chose
As shown, it keeps reporting as version 3.13
Does anyone have any idea how I can correct this behavior?
I tried uninstalling version 3.13, updating my environment variables, restarting PyCharm and my computer, clearing out all pre-existing interpreters, everything I could think of. Nothing caused this behavior to change. I select version 3.7 in the path, and then it reports as Python 3.13 (which, later on, causes version issues when attempting to import packages).

Does this answer your question? How to select Python version in PyCharm?

Try setting default to Python 3.7. To do this, do the following:

Type in Default Apps in the Windows search bar.
Type .py when it asks for a file type.
Browse for the required option in the menu. If not available, browse through the computer to find the version and set it as default.

The above helped in VSCode. Hope it works in PyCharm.

I don't know if this will help but in PyCharm Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Code is incompatible with specific Python versions you can choose which version of python you want to use for your project.
